# Frobenius inner product problem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be a given symmetric $n \times n$ real matrix. Let $A$ be a linear operator on real antisymmetric $n \times n$ matrices given by $A(X) = MXM$

1. What is the largest possible number of complex eigenvalues that
   the operator $A$ may have.
2. What is the largest possible number
   of eigenvalues of $A$ that are not real? Hint: Regard the space of
   $n \times n$ matrices as an inner product space with respect to the
   Frobenius inner product $(M,K) = \hbox{Tr}(MK^T)$.

For part $1.$ I got $n(n-1)/2$ number of eigenvalues $A$ may have
I do not know how to use the hint to solve the problem. Please, help.

Comment: Part1 is done, just part 2

Answer (score 1):

All the eigenvalues of $A$ are real, because $A$ is symmetric as operator on the subspace of ${\cal A}_n$ of $n\times n$ antisymmetric  real matrices. For $X,Y$ from ${\cal A}_n$ we have
$$\eqalign{
\langle A(X),Y\rangle&=\hbox{Tr}(A(X)Y^T)=\hbox{Tr}(MXMY^T)=\hbox{Tr}(XMY^TM)\cr
&=\hbox{Tr}(X(MYM)^T)=\hbox{Tr}(X(A(Y))^T )=\langle X,A(Y)\rangle
}
$$
Thus, all the eigenvalues of $A$ are real.

Comment: A is not symmetric, A is operator works on antisymmetric space, so that A is an antisymmetric matrix. However, it works still:) Thank you so much. I got it

Comment: @user73195, No, $A$ is a symmetric operator on the space of antisymmetric matrices. As a simple example consider the case when $M=I_n$, then $A$ is the identity operator on ${\cal A}_n$ and it is clearly not antisymmetric.

Comment: You mean A must be symmetric? Is there any way to argue if it is not?(I mean if it is an antisymmetric). One more thing, how Tr(MXMY^T) = Tr(XMY^TM)?

Comment: To see the point consider a $2\times 2$ example, or $3\times 3$ example and write the matrix of $A$ in with respect to the canonical basis of ${\cal A}_n$. Any way I have proved that $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: I trust you, how about the second part? is not that the order of the matrices in a product stiff? how can you switch them to get MXMY^t = XMY^tM. I am sorry for my bad knowledge.

Comment: Because $\hbox{Tr}(AB)=\hbox{Tr}(BA)$, this a property of the trace of matrices and you can check it from the definition.